# Make default value of Segment unselected

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to load a segment control with an array. When I do it selects Male as the default. I want neither male or female to be selected , both unselected as default.

```
- (id)initWithAnimal:(ITAnimal *)Animal isEdit:(BOOL)isEdit
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    _Animal = Animal;
    _genders = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Male", @"Female", nil];
    if (!_Animal) {
        _Animal = [[ITData sharedObject] managedObjectFromName:@"ITAnimal"];
        _Animal.gender = [_genders objectAtIndex:0];

    }
    _isEdit = isEdit;

    // gender controll
    self.genderControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:_genders];
    [self.genderControl addTarget:self action:@selector(genderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
    }
    return self;
}





}
else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
    BOOL isIn = NO;
    for (id view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        if ([view isEqual:self.genderControl]) isIn = YES;
    }
    if (!isIn) [cell.contentView addSubview:self.genderControl];

    [cell.detailTextLabel setHidden:_isEdit];
    [self.genderControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:[_genders indexOfObject:content]];

    [self.genderControl setHidden:!_isEdit];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably use :

```
[self.genderControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:UISegmentedControlNoSegment];
```

[*From Apple's doc:*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html)

> The default value is UISegmentedControlNoSegment (no segment selected)
>   until the user touches a segment. Set this property to -1 to turn off
>   the current selection. 
>   UISegmentedControl ignores this property when
>   the control is in momentary mode.

Comment: I have the above `[self.genderControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:[_genders indexOfObject:content]];`

Comment: Explain please the problem because the code you edited does not explain it

Comment: By adding `[self.genderControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:-1];` into isEdit state it worked, however, every time I reedit it, it goes back to Unselected for both

Comment: Correction it may unselect but saves to database as Male still. I am quite confused what is going on...

Comment: Do you mean that segmentedcontrol is shown as unselected, and selected index is not -1 ?

Comment: yes initially it was selected as Male, but changed `[self.genderControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:[_genders indexOfObject:content]];` to `[self.genderControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:-1]];` Now it is unselected as default but when I save it saves Male to database still.

Comment: Do not know, make sure that it is not your mistake NSLog(@"selected segment: %i" ,self.genderControl.selectedSegmentIndex);

Comment: Thanks, well this statement answered the question so thats fair, thank you, I will look over the code to see if there are other issues preventing null from being saved

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for

```
[segmentcontrol setSelectedSegmentIndex:-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still a problem for somebody.. But if you are using storyBoards.. select the segmentedIndex you placed on viewController and in attributes Inspector --> Segmented Control --> Behavior uncheck the checkbox for selected..

Answer (score 0):

If you are here looking for a solution for SwiftUI, just set your currentSelection value to -1 as default.

```
   struct Parent: View {
    
      @State private var currentSelection = -1
      
      var segmentOptions = ["Green", "Blue"]
      
      var body: some View {
        HStack {
            
            Picker(selection: $currentSelection, label: Text("What is your favorite color?")) {
                ForEach(0..<segmentOptions.count) { index in
                    Text(self.segmentOptions[index]).tag(index)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        }
      }
    }
```